# Cumsum of column value equals to

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID Category Parameter Color
1    1       1          Red
1    1       2          Green
1    1       3          Red
1    2       1          Green
1    2       2          Red
```

And I want to add a column that does the cumsum of red values, i.e, the number of red values that were seen until that row. That should be grouped by the column category and parameter. The output for this particular case, would be something like this:

```
ID Category Parameter Color count_red_category  count_red_parameter
1    1       1          Red        1                   1
1    1       2          Green      1                   0
1    1       3          Red        2                   1
1    2       1          Green      0                   0
1    2       2          Red        1                   1
```

It should count the number of reds for a category and for a parameter. One category can have many parameters, therefore the number of reds in a category should be the sum of all reds in the parameters with that specific category.

What is the best way of doing this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for compare for equality, convert to numbers and then use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
s = df['Color'].eq('Red').astype(int)
#alternative
#s = df['Color'].eq('Red').view('i1')

df1 = df.assign(COUNT = s)
df['count_red_categories'] = df1.groupby(['Category', 'ID'])['COUNT'].cumsum()
df['count_red_parameters'] = df1.groupby(['Parameter', 'ID'])['COUNT'].cumsum()

print (df)
   ID  Category  Parameter  Color  count_red_categories  count_red_parameters
0   1         1          1    Red                     1                     1
1   1         1          2  Green                     1                     0
2   1         1          3    Red                     2                     1
3   1         2          1  Green                     0                     1
4   1         2          2    Red                     1                     1
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an update to my question. I was not what I intended to ask :)

Comment: why `.astype(int)` or `view`? I think  it isn't neccesary here

Comment: @ansev - For me it return boolean column, so necessary

Comment: I don't mean to bother you, but how would I group all this by the ID? Because the ID repeats itself in this example but there are more IDS in the dataframe. The way it is done now, the cumsum is being done to the whole dataframe and not for each ID.

Comment: @LuísCosta - Understand, give me a sec.

Comment: @LuísCosta - Can you check now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213100/discussion-between-luis-costa-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
df[['count_red_categories', 'count_red_parameters']] = df[['Category', 'Parameter']].eq('Red').cumsum()
print(df)

   ID Category Parameter  count_red_categories  count_red_parameters
0   1      Red     Green                     1                     0
1   1      Red       Red                     2                     1
2   1    Green     Green                     2                     1
3   1    Green       Red                     2                     2
4   1      Red       Red                     3                     3
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an update to my question. I was not what I intended to ask :)

Comment: in that case you can use@jezrael solution but you don't need to use `astype(int)`..